# Replace image url with img tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to replace URLs in a string with img tags.

I have this working but, it also replaces URLs inside an anchor tag.

If i have :

```
 $string = 'Hi, https://example.com/logo.png,
     <a href="https://example.com/banner.png">https://example.com/banner.png</a>';
```

It makes it look like :

```
Hi, <img src="https://example.com/logo.png" />,
     <a href="<img src="https://example.com/banner.png" />"><img src="https://example.com/banner.png" /></a>
```

And this is what i use for replacement :

```
return preg_replace_callback('/https?:\/\/(.*?)\.(jpg|png|gif)(\?\w+=\w+)?/i',    function($matches){ 
        return '<img src="'.$matches[0].'" />'; 
}, $string);
```

How can i make it ignore anchor tags.

Thank you.

Comment: show us how did you replace the string, regexp?

Comment: Would this help? http://blog.codinghorror.com/excluding-matches-with-regular-expressions/.  I'm not sure exactly how to implement it myself, but looks like it could work.

Comment: Fixed using regular expression lookbehind

`
return preg_replace_callback('/(?<!href="|src=")https?:\/\/(.*?)\.(jpg|png|gif)(\?\w+=\w+)?/i', function($matches){
        return '<img src="'.$matches[0].'" />';
    }, $string);
`

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regex for HTML manipulation directly. Instead, you can use DOM manipulation using `DOMDocument`. Find all the text nodes in the HTML string and replace image URLs with image tags safely.

```
<?php

$string = 'Hi, https://example.com/logo.png,
<a href="https://example.com/banner.png">https://example.com/banner.png</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();

// This loads the HTML string in a special way to handle utf and 
// not append any extra HTML tags
$dom->loadHtml(mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

// Get the text nodes
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//text()') as $node) {
    // Replace the text nodes with the replaced HTML fragments
    $replaced = preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/[^ ]+?(?:\.jpg|\.png|\.gif))/', '<img src="$1" alt="$1" />', $node->data);
    $frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    $frag->appendXML($replaced);
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($frag, $node);
}

echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

**Output:**

```
<p>Hi, <img src="https://example.com/logo.png" alt="https://example.com/logo.png">,
<a href="https://example.com/banner.png"><img src="https://example.com/banner.png" alt="https://example.com/banner.png"></a></p>
```

If you want to exclude image URLs between the anchors as well, you can instead use

```
$xpath->query('//text()[not(ancestor::a)]');
```

**Output:**

```
<p>Hi, <img src="https://example.com/logo.png" alt="https://example.com/logo.png">,
<a href="https://example.com/banner.png">https://example.com/banner.png</a></p>
```

---

I used this regex for the demo. Please modify it for your purposes.

```
preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/[^ ]+?(?:\.jpg|\.png|\.gif))/', '<img src="$1" alt="$1" />', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

An initial try would be use `negative look-behind and positive look-ahead` to check if the image does not start with a `"` or end with a `"`.

```
$pattern = '/(?<!")https?:\/\/(.*?)\.(jpg|png|gif)(?!")(\?\w+=\w+)?/i';
return preg_replace_callback( $pattern, function( $matches ) { 
    return '<img src="'.$matches[0].'" />'; 
}, $string);
```

Hope this helps.